# Getting seg fault in gdb (debugging)

Tags: c

I am a bit new to pointers. I am receiving this error while running the code below specified using gcc compiler in ububtu.

```
Error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de7c13 in _dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:235
235 dl-fini.c: No such file or directory
```

***code***
.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cmath>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    void update(int *a,int *b) {
        int *c;
        *c=*a;
        *c=abs(*a+*b);
        *b=abs(*a-*b);
        *a=*c;
    }

    int main() {
        int a, b;
        int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;

        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        update(pa, pb);
        printf("%d\n%d", a, b);

        return 0;
    }
```

please post any suggestions/solutions regarding this.

Comment: Change `int *c;` to `int c;` and each `*c` to `c`. You either allocate memory for a pointer, or simply just put that variable on the stack.

Comment: This particular problem would be identified for you with the appropriate options to your compile.  From g++ (and clang++):  "warning: ‘c’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]".

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Kudos - your code was not hard to compile, SO noobs early contributions often do not.  It appears to be more 'C' than 'C++' (not the same language) so please check your tag.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is what you were trying to do.

```
void update(int *a,int *b) {
    int c;
    c=*a;
    c=abs(*a+*b);
    *b=abs(*a-*b);
    *a=c; 
}
```

Comment: Thanx Rob :), i thout that *c=*a would copy the value of a to c.

Comment: It would but you had not initialized it so it blew chuncks at you with a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're never allocating memory for that pointer `c` declared in your `update()` function:

```
int *c; // <<< not initialized
```

You must allocate memory to use that pointer:

```
int *c = new int();
```

and free it when leaving your function:

```
delete c;
```

---

The easier way of course is just to have a variable

```
int c = *a;
```

on the functions local stack, and omit the dereferencing:

```
    c=abs(*a+*b);
// ^ Note the * was removed
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact your tagged your question with `c++` and your code has nothing to do with `c++` here is a *real* `c++` code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void update(int &a,int &b) {
   int c;
   c=a;
   c=abs(a+b);
   b=abs(a-b);
   a=c;
}

int main() {
   int a, b;

   std::cin >> a;
   std::cin >> b;
   update(a, b);
   std::cout << a << std::endl << b << std::endl;

}
```

I strongly recommend you use some compiler flags which would have already warn you while the compilation and even the code would not have been generated.

For `g++` my suggested options are:

```
-std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra
```